# What's the purpose of this line code " _ = Queue(&FIFO{})"?

Tags: go

I don't get the idea of one line of golang code in [kunbernets code](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/ef81ee0960bf57e94c697d674a1a8f5694c0ec9a/tools/cache/fifo.go#L118)

```golang
var (
    _ = Queue(&FIFO{}) // FIFO is a Queue
)
```

Comment: Perhaps it's a way to confirm that FIFO satisfies the interface, Queue.  If a maintainer changes things so that FIFO does not satisfy the interface, the compiler will prevent the program from being built and clearly describe the problem.

Comment: Ctt, Thanks. I googled the internet according to your answer.  It is the case.